# get data from firebase orderByChild doesn't order the items

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm looping over two references on firebase database to get some data and show them on a page. I would like to get the results ordered by their name, but it doesn't work, and keeps returning the elements in the order they are on database.
This is my code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/point_of_interest/'+this.poi.chiave+'/tags/')
var ref1 = firebase.database().ref('/tag/');

let tagShow = [];
ref.once('value', function(snapshot){ //ciclo sui tag
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key; //chiave tag
      var exists = false;
      //ref1.orderByChild("nome").once('value', function(snapshot){
        ref1.child("nome").orderByValue().once('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
          var childKey1 = childSnapshot.key;
          if (childKey == childKey1){ //se ne trovo uno uguale, eisste nella lista dei tag del poi
              exists = true;
          }
          return false;
        })
      }).then(a => {
        if (!exists){
          tagShow.push(childSnapshot); //push the list to be displayed
        }
      })         
    return false;
  })
}).then(a=>{
  //do something
})
```

I've tried both with `ref.orderByChild("nome")` and `ref.child("nome").orderByValue()`, but the result is the same.
This is how my `tag` reference looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database queries operate on each child node under the location where you execute the query. When you call `orderByValue()` it orders on the value of each child node. This is useful when you have a structure like this:

```
node: {
  child1: "c"
  child2: "b"
  child3: "a"
}
```

Here using ref.orderByValue() would order the nodes on their value: `a`, `b`, `c`.

But in your case the values that you want to sort on are one level lower in the JSON. In Firebase speak that is a child node, so you're looking for `orderByChild(...)` here:

```
ref1.orderByChild("nome").once('value', function(snapshot){
```